# Iterate through rows in hyperspectral image

Tags: python, image, iteration, spectral-python

I have code that displays a hyperspectral images (cube).

I have to images:
Image 1:  hyperspectral image that has N number of  rows and N number of columns. 
Image 2: hyperspectral image that has only one row, but it has the same number of columns as image 1.

I want to create iteration:
for each row in image 1, I want to subtract 
 the values from image 2.
so if for example in column one the value in image 1 is 10 and in image 2 is 4, the new image will have pixel with value 6.

The problem is that  I don't know how to iterate through rows in images.

This is what I have tried up to now:

```
import spectral.io.envi as envi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from spectral import *
import numpy as np

#Create the image path
#the path 
img_path = r'N:\this\is\path\emptyname_2019-08-13_11-05-46\capture'
cali_path=r'N:\more\path'

#the specific file 
img_file = 'emptyname_2019-08-13_11-05-46.hdr'
img_dark= 'DARKREF_emptyname_2019-08-13_11-05-46.hdr'
cali_hdr= 'Radiometric_1x1.hdr'
cali_img = 'Radiometric_1x1.cal'

#load the images
img= envi.open(os.path.join(img_path,img_file)).load()
img_dark= envi.open(os.path.join(img_path,img_dark)).load()
img_cali= envi.open(os.path.join(cali_path,cali_hdr), image = os.path.join(cali_path,cali_img)).load()

wavelength=[float(i) for i in img.metadata['wavelength']]

#here I have created image 2- the image with the 1 row 
dark_1024=img_dark.mean(axis=0)


#bad attempt  to iterate through each row.
for index, row in img.iterrows():
    img-img_dark
```

> AttributeError: 'ImageArray' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Any idea how can I "grab" only the rows and create new image with the new values?

Comment: Using `iterrows` is only possible with pandas DataFrames, right? What is the shape of the `img`? Can you loop over each pixel with `for pixel in itertools.product(range(n_rows), range(n_columns)): img[pixel] ...`?

Comment: the sape of the image is 13000 rows and 1024 columns. The shape of image 2 is 1 row with 1024 columns.

Comment: What are the rows and columns in your images? Did you reshape the 3D cube images to 2D arrays?